# How do I point Maven to use Java 8 and not Java 7 on my AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-ec2

I recently installed Maven on my `AWS EC2` instance using following commands:

```
sudo wget https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo yum install -y apache-maven
```

It brought in `Java 7` dependency along with it. I already have `Java 8` installed though.

Quick googling showed me that you can change the pointer to Java 8 using the `alternatives` command which I tried but no luck.

**$ mvn -v**

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T07:58:13Z)
Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven
Java version: 1.7.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.201.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**$ java -version**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

**$ javac -version**

```
javac 1.7.0_201
```

**$ sudo alternatives --config java**

```
There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
*  2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

**$ sudo alternatives --config javac**

```
There is 1 program that provides 'javac'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac
```

For some reason I just see one option in the above `sudo alternatives --config javac` command.

Please guide.

Comment: try using openjdk-devel ?

Comment: How to use it ?

Comment: Maven uses the `JAVA_HOME` variable, so all you need to do is `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/` before calling the `mvn` command (assuming this is a JDK installation)

Comment: Your need to install it `yum install ...`

Comment: @ernest_k - Yes that worked but just once. As soon as close and session and relogin it goes back to `Java 7`. I would like both `mvn -v` and `javac` command to be in sync and using `Java 8` always so that there are no discrepancies.

Comment: @user2325154 That's right. If you need the environment variable to be available in all shell sessions, then you have to add that `export` command to your profile script (`~/.bashrc` or whatever your system uses)

Comment: @ernest_k - Added `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64` in my `.bash_profile` file. That fixed it for `mvn -v` command but `javac` still shows `javac 1.7.0_201`. Any pointers for that?

Comment: That should be fine, you can have maven use a different version of java than your standard `java`/`javac/ calls. But if you want to fix it for normal calls as well, then you need to change the path variable as well in your init script. `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64` then `export PATH = $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @ernest_k - Added but no luck. Is there any Maven installation that comes prebuilt with Java 8?